# .htaccess mod_rewrite just broke the site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

in the following .htaccess file...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^getpearson.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.getpearson\.com" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^redesign_03012010/mock-up/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /redesign_03012010/mock-up/index.php?page=$1§ion=$2 [PT]
RewriteRule ^redesign_03012010/mock-up/([^/]+)$ /redesign_03012010/mock-up/index.php?page=$1 [PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?test=1&page=$1§ion=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?test=1&page=$1 [L]
```

i removed modified the last 3 lines from:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?test=1&page=$1§ion=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?test=1&page=$1 [L]
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1§ion=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

...hence only removing the 'test=1&' url variable, and now it no werkie... what is the logic to this crazy htaccess lingo?  it stumps me.  anyhow, i did a php work-around until i can figure this out, so no worries, but please help!  thanks!

Comment: i removed modified the last 3 lines from:

should be

i modified the last 3 lines from:

Answer (score 2):

"no werkie" is a little vague... The edit you made to the rules seems fine.  Maybe the index.php page is expecting the "test" variable to be present and will crash if it isn't?

Instead of removing the "test" variable from the query string, try just changing "test=1" to "test=0" instead.

Comment: @Lucas - any chance you uploaded the file as binary instead of text?  It could be that there are windows line breaks in the file that are breaking the .htaccess file.  Apache is pretty picky about those files - one small error and you'll just get 500 errors on every page of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas,
I think you're last two rules are missing a / before the pattern. And also take out [PT] it's not appropriate in this case.

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?test=1&page=$1&section=$2
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /index.php?test=1&page=$1 [L]
```

Tom

Comment: regular uses of this are working, just not for that directory

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem in your `index.php` file, not `.htaccess`. What happens when you access `index.php` without `test=1` directly instead of via the rewritten URL? I suspect it's configured to throw a 500 error in that situation.

Comment: figured it out... very simple, actually had to do with php_tidy_parse... error was actually 404 not found due to an &amp; as opposed to a ?... it's always 'some mundane detail', as michael bolton so greatly put it.

Comment: Dude, chill out with the comments. You can edit them for a while instead of posting a bunch in quick succession, and there's really no need to say things like "oh... hold on..."

Comment: " there's really no need to say things like 'oh... hold on...' "

why not, do you really want me wasting your time when i realize things might be ok on my end?